# rewrite rule for an URL with 2 queries

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My URL looks like this:

```
example.com/index.php?f=directory&s=page
```

I want it to be like this instead:

```
example.com/directory/page
```

my rewrite rules look like this right now:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+).html$ https://www.example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

it appears to work but not quite because if I call the queries in PHP I get something like this:

```
print $_GET['f'] */ it prints nothing
print $_GET['s'] */ it prints directory/page
```

which is not what I intend. How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: What other directives do you have? The directive you posted "kind of" does the opposite. The URL needs to already be like `/directory/page` in your application.

Comment: i kinda posted the wrong snippet. I just edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
> ```

Do it like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?f=$1&s=$2 [L]
```

Request `/directory/page` and it internally rewrites the request to `index.php?f=directory&s=page`.

By making the regex more specific, the filesystem checks can probably be avoided.

To redirect from `index.php?f=directory&s=page` to `/directory/page` (if these URLs have already been indexed and/or linked to by third parties), then add the following redirect *before* the above directive:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f=([^&]+)&s=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

But you must already be linking to the canonical `/directory/page` URL in your application.

Test with 302s to avoid potential caching issues. Clear your browser cache before testing.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
> ```

You are only assigning a single URL parameter `s`, so yes, `$_GET['f']` will indeed be empty.